# How to run vscode on local machine after cloning from GitHub repository

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have first clone the vscode from the github repository which is https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode.git

I have installed all the packages using yarn

Using "yarn compile" I have compiled the code successfully.

Now what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the [VSCode Wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#prerequisites)

The build/compilation is done with:

```
cd vscode
yarn
yarn run watch
```

As mentioned in [Microsoft/vscode issue 49424](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49424):

> if you build under Windows the generated executable is is a sibling folder to the vscode folder named `VSCode-win32-x64`.
>   The executable is still named `Code - OSS.exe`.